# How to call a Component (Directive) on Click of a button or a Tile in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am using Ionic, my layout is **tabs**. On one tab, I have a button, **on click** of that button I want to call a component/directive and display its content and hide the current content that is there. How do I go about achieving that?

Comment: either use *ngIf in your template based on a value changed on click or use a ion-router-outlet inside the tabs and use navigation to change the route

Comment: @GérômeGrignon thank you very much, *ngIf worked fine. I hope it's a good design pattern to go with that solution.

Comment: sure it's a common pattern to display content conditionally